# Is it possible set `null` value for non mapped columns using JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have an existing table with a lot of fields, some of them without default value, like bellow.

In my entity class **i just want to declare some fields**.

When i try to insert a new row, i'm getting the error `Field 'hours_work' doesn't have a default value`.

```
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
|  ...                                                                  
| hours_work             | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| locations              | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ...
```

Then, i set `sql_mode` to `''`

```
mysql> set @@sql_mode='';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

So I'm able to insert row by command line, but not using my application

```
mysql> insert into MyTable (column1) values ('test value');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 84 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

I tried set `sql_mode` in URL connection like i saw in some posts, but didn't work

**application.yml**

```
main:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database?sessionVariables=sql_mode=''
```

I appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: alter your table so hours_work becomes Nullable

Comment: I can not touch in current database structure =(

Comment: so you dont have the choice only to set some text to it

Comment: damn, thanks for help

Comment: you 're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it adding`jdbcCompliantTruncation=false` to MySQL URL connection, according to Sébastien explanation below.

> Sébastien,
>
> The driver needs the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode enabled to enforce JDBC
>   compliance on truncation checks.
>
> If you can't use STRICT_TRANS_TABLES as part of your sql_mode, then
>   you'll have to disable truncation checks by adding
>   "jdbcCompliantTruncation=false" as a URL configuration parameter.

According to Sébastien, at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23371

So now URL connection looks likes

```
main:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/edirectory_domain?jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&sessionVariables=sql_mode=''
```